# Black screen on app launch when using i18n from JSON files

Tags: json, flutter, dart, internationalization

I am attempting to build my own implementation of a system for localizing strings for internationalization in Flutter apps, using Flutter's `LocalizationsDelegate`, and loading the localized strings from JSON files (one json file for each locale).

Everything works fine, but when the app is launched, there's a lapse of some milliseconds in which the screen goes black. The reason for this is that, since I am loading the JSON files using `json.decode`, the way I am retrieving the localized strings is asynchronous. The app loads its `MaterialApp` widget and **then** starts parsing the JSONs for localization. That is when the app goes black until it parses the JSON successfully.

Here is my implementation of my i18n system:

```dart
class Localization extends LocaleCodeAware with LocalizationsProvider {
  Localization(this.locale) : super(locale.toString());

  final Locale locale;

  static Localization of(BuildContext context) =>
      Localizations.of<Localization>(context, Localization);
}

class AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<Localization> {
  const AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'es'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<Localization> load(Locale locale) async {
    final localization = Localization(locale);
    await localization.load();
    return localization;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:example/resources/asset_paths.dart' as paths;

abstract class LocaleCodeAware {
  LocaleCodeAware(this.localeCode);

  final String localeCode;
}

mixin LocalizationsProvider on LocaleCodeAware {
  static Map<String, String> _values;

  Future<void> load() async {
    final string = await rootBundle.loadString('${paths.i18n}$localeCode.json');
    final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(string);
    _values = jsonMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
  }

  String get appTitle => _values['appTitle'];
}
```

Here is my `main.dart` file, with its `MaterialApp` widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
    localizationsDelegates: [
      const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
    ],
    supportedLocales: const [Locale("en"), Locale("es")],
    home: const AppNavigator(),
  );
}
```

If instead of having the localized strings in JSON files, I assign a `Map<String, String>` to my `_values` map, and I load the strings directly from there, the black screen issue is gone, because the values are hardcoded and can be loaded synchronously.

So my question is, how can I have my app wait in splash screen until the localized strings are loaded from the JSON files?

Comment: Please show all the code in `main.dart` as well as your usage of `MaterialApp` (which may or may not be in `main.dart`)

Comment: Sure, I've just edited my question to add my `main.dart` code.

Comment: Do you need to use JSON files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any errors in your logs? The black screen could only be caused by 1. The current route not building a visible page or 2. The `build()` function of the current route throwing exceptions.

As for loading the localizations while on the splash screen, you can do that within your `main()` function:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  List<Locale> locales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;
  // ... logic to decide which locale to use and load localizations for

  final string = await rootBundle.loadString('${paths.i18n}$localeCode.json');
  final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(string);

  runApp(ExampleApp(jsonMap));
}
```

This way, you can read the JSON file and convert it to a `Map` while on the splash screen, and then pass it to `ExampleApp`, which can in turn pass it to `AppLocalizationsDelegate`, which can store it as a local variable and use it within `load()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to pre-load assets before the app intializes, and that would seem to work, but, if you review the snippet you've posted, you will quickly notice that I would need to access the `$localeCode` variable before initializing the app. And I don't know how to do that, since the locale code is retrieved from the initializations in `MaterialApp`

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to retrieve the list of device locales before calling `runApp` - note that `WidgetsBinding.instance` can only be called after `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`. You can then add your own logic, based on locale ordering, locales supported by your app, user preferences within your app, etc. to decide which `localeCode` to use.

Comment: Does this not answer your question?

Comment: It does! Sorry, I forgot about this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

checkout [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package , its simpler than the most out there